# How do I find the missing Gold Skulltulas?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I've almost completely finished Ocarina of Time now, and I'd like to get 100% completion just for the fun of it. The big problem is the Gold Skulltulas.

I've heard there's some sort of indicator on the map of which regions aren't complete, but I'm not sure how it works, or what exactly it shows (e.g. does it include Skulltulas in dungeons?).

How can I find the last 20 or so Skulltulas I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, the map will show an indicator that notifies you when you collected all the skulltulas in the area.

For world map areas, the skulltula icon will be directly left of the name of the map region, as seen in the below image. Skulltulas within dungeons of these regions do *not* count towards this total. Any area that has its own dungeon map would have its own section of skulltulas to collect that are separate from these 'overworld' skulltulas.
[image]

For dungeons, it will do the same indicator, where the skulltula icon will be next to the name of the dungeon on the dungeon map. However, unlike the world map, you'll need to actually go into the dungeon to see the dungeon map and confirm you've collected them all.

Unfortunately, there's no way to know within the map section which skulltulas you've already collected, so there may be some backtracking and rechecking until you found all within a region.

Comment: I have the Gold Skulltula icon on every overworld area and (I am 99% sure but currently checking) every dungeon but I am still missing 4 ><

Comment: @dtw if the overworld ones are all covered (for both child and adult link), the rest should be in 'dungeon' areas. Be aware though to look in all areas, too, not just the 'major' dungeons. E.g. don't forget smaller dungeons like the bottom of the well.

Comment: They were in the Fire Temple, after all...